# Desplegar proyecto AngularCLI en sevidor NodeJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, linux

He concluido un proyecto usando Angular CLI y tengo necesidad de desplegarlo en un servidor Linux el cual tiene actualmente instalado una versión de NodeJs.La estructura del proyecto construido es la que muestro a continuación:

[image: Esta es la estructura del proyecto Angular una vez construido]

Mi duda es acerca de como conseguir desplegar este proyecto en el servidor de NodeJs, tengo entendido que es posible sin necesidad de instalar Angular. De no ser así por favor me vendría muy bien cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún hosting o dominio en el que querer desplegar tu aplicación?

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli es una herramienta de desarrollo con la que puedes tener un ambiente de desarrollo y tambien generar las de produccion, en tu servidor de node, apache o iis.

Solo debes ejecutar en la linea de comandos:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Esto genera los archivos necesarios en la carpeta que hayas configurado por defecto suele ser `dist` y hace algunas optimizacion para produccion

En caso de que tu aplicacion de angular no este sobre el dominio `www.misiotio.com/` si no en una subcarpeta como `www.misiotio.com/miapp/angular/`

```
ng build --base-href=/miapp/angular/
```

Y ya puedes copiar los archivos y publicar tu app.

[Documentación de angular-cli para despliegue](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

[Documentación de angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estás liando: Una vez que has generado tu aplicación con Angular y has hecho el build, simplemente tienes que servirlo desde un servidor web. Lo normal es [usar Apache](https://trellat.es/angular-en-apache/) o Ngnix (los dos más populares), pero por supuesto también podrías servirlo desde un servidor creado desde NodeJS. Si es esto lo que buscas, podrías montarlo usando [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) de un modo muy rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada entiendo que tu servidor NodeJS ya está creado, en caso de que no, debes crearlo, te recomiendo buscar un cursillo básico en youtube sobre NodeJS - Express.

En caso de que ya tengas creado tu backend y quieres añadir tu proyecto de Angular al frontend sigue estos pasos:

---

Tras realizar el ng build y tener una carpeta BUILD/DIST (o como la denomines) debes realizar lo siguiente:

1º Arrastra el contenido de la carpeta BUILD/DIST al proyecto de NodeJS. Mételo en una carpeta llamada "views" en la raíz del proyecto.
Añado imagen de un proyecto mío y su estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2º Añade el siguiente código a tu index del servidor de NodeJS:

```
const path = __dirname + '/views/';
app.use(express.static(path));

app.get('/', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.sendFile(path + 'index.html');
});
```

Ejecuta tu aplicación NodeJS y busca localhost:{puerto_que_uses} en tu buscador.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.